# Installing gmpy on Windows - pip install doesn't work

Tags: windows, installation, python

I am trying to install the gmpy package on Windows 10. "pip install gmpy" stops with an error message about requiring Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0. Various accounts online suggest that the answer is to install Visual Studio with the Visual C++ build utilities. This I have done. "pip install gmpy" after this results in a lengthy error message:

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\stephen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\stephen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/gmpy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/gmpy.obj
gmpy.c
c:\users\stephen\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-m5ym7nd7\gmpy\src\gmpy.h(30): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gmp.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Various other sources suggest going to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy, where various .whl files can be downloaded. Unfortunately I get no better results with these:

```
C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads>pip install gmpy-1.17-cp34-none-win32.whl
gmpy-1.17-cp34-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads>pip install gmpy-1.17-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
gmpy-1.17-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have tried various different version numbers of the .whl files, with the same result. Is there some other way to do this that I have missed?

Comment: `gmp.h` is either missing completely or not in your include path.